# Is there a limit to Gundam 00 Raiser's power?

Tags: mobile-suit-gundam

From **Gundam 00**, one of the noteably most powerful Mobile Suits in the series and perhaps in the Gundam Universe was **00 Raiser**.

It is seen in at least one episode where 00 Raiser enters Trans-Am mode and uses what I believe was the GN sword III as a gun and shot a **massive beam** that engulfed multiple warships and it's enemy all in that single shot. But there was **no obvious indication that Raiser couldn't just do this *again and again***, and yet it **only used it as a boss move once or twice** in a climactic fight.

I know 00 Raiser is equipped with 2 GN Drives and such can **to some degree have power-regenerative capabilities**, but is there some limitation that prevents Raiser from using that attack again and again?